# Catch NSException c# xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, core-bluetooth

I've been trying to catch a `NSException` thrown by `CancelPeripheralConnection`, however it keeps saying it needs to be derived from system.exception.

```
try
{
     if (device.NativeDevice as CBPeripheral != null)
     {
          this.central.CancelPeripheralConnection(device.NativeDevice as CBPeripheral);
     }
     else
     {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Null CBPeripheral Disconnect");
     }
}
catch (Foundation.NSErrorException)
{
    //works
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Caught ns Error exception");
}
catch (Foundation.NSException)
{
    //doesn't work
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Caught ns exception");
}
```

I keep getting the following in my output window when it crashes 
`2016-07-05 08:41:16.579 BadgeManageriOS[1066:685789] *** Assertion failure in -[CBCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:force:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth-327.3/CBCentralManager.m:332`

my question is how am i supposed to catch the `NSException` as i can't seem to find any documentation where people catch it in the place where it throws it.

Answer (score 0):

An ObjC `NSException` have a C# managed wrapper class: `MonoTouchException`

```
MonoTouchException thrownException = null;
try {
  ~~~~
} catch (MonoTouchException ex) {
    thrownException = ex;
}
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException/

> This is a wrapper class for the Objective-C NSException class.

Comment: Hey, This didn't work unfortunately.but also i'm using xamarion ios not classic monotouch so i only have access to https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.MonoTouchException/

Comment: it claims tio be the same but maybe it doesn't work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think NSException is something you shouldn't handle yourself. This is thrown natively. Check out: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18427